# how to show the background image to a div by using props in react

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I am using react and now I want to add a background image in a div. the image url is coming from props. But the background is not shown the code of the inline css is following

```
  import React from 'react'
    
    
    export default function City(props) {
      const image = props.img ;      
return (
        <div className='col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-10 ' style={{
          backgroundImage: `url(${image})`}}>
          <p>{image}</p>
        
        </div>
      )
    }
```

Now what I do to show the background image in a div?

Answer (score 0):

You're almost right, just add the `height` and `width` of the div.

```js
function City(props) {
  const image = props.img;
  return (
    <div
      style={{ height:"300px", width:"300px", backgroundImage: `url(${image})` }}
    >
      <p>{image}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
    
    
ReactDOM.render(
  <City img="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/ogw/ADea4I6PTtu7DPMQ_R27dQUjfvh2Zol_ehq8vIxq8c3DOw=s32-c-mo" />,
  document.body
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In `styled components` and `material ui` libraries you can pass props to styles like so:

#### Styled Components version:

https://styled-components.com/docs/basics#adapting-based-on-props

#### Material UI version:

https://mui.com/styles/basics/#adapting-based-on-props

So in the end you can pass your props further to the styles as props.